# Excel - Difference between =$L$136 and =L136

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, ms-office

I'm using Excel, I have this formula with `$L$136`:

> =(N149/((1+$L$136)^N147))

I obtain the correct result to calculate VAL. But without `$L$`, i.e. `L136`,

> =(N149/((1+L136)^N147))

I obtain a different result.

Can you explain me the difference between both?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I know that exists the function VAL.

Comment: The difference is that `=$L$136` will be a absolute cell reference. It will **not** change if you copy or fill that formula within a sheet or if it will get into another base-cell-context in conditional formatting. The `=L136` will be a relative cell reference. It **will** change if you copy or fill that formula within a sheet or if it will get into another base-cell-context in conditional formatting.

Comment: @AxelRichter thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no difference. The only difference happens when you copy the contents of the cell to a different cell. Without $, the address component (row and/or column, both or only one) is treated as relative, with $ it is absolute.

If you copy

```
=(N149/((1+$L$136)^N147))
```

one column to the right, then the formula in the new cell should be

```
=(O149/((1+$L$136)^O147))
```

However, if you copy

```
=(N149/((1+L136)^N147))
```

to one cell to the right, it should change to

```
=(O149/((1+M136)^O147))
```

Comment: Good answer -- though perhaps you could mention such things as the `F4` shortcut for adding them in a formula, as well as the existence and meaning of 1 dollar sign variations.